# ControllerAdvice, ExceptionHandler and try catch block in RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, annotations

I have generic question about `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler`. I have a rest controller annotated `@RestController` that has 2 apis. If argument validation fails, it throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. I created `ExceptionHandler` to handle this:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getBindingResult().getGlobalError().getDefaultMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

If I want to log something when this exception happens, can I just add line of code before `return` statement like:

`LOG.info("something happened");`

Will it log it and then return BAD_REQUEST back to the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to log something when this exception happens, can I just add line of code before return statement like:
>
> LOG.info("something happened");
>
> Will it log it and then return BAD_REQUEST back to the caller?

Yes. That's the purpose of using `@ExceptionHandler`s. They help to reduce the code to handle exceptions across several rest endpoints defined in your project. This also serves as the single point to log exceptions, thus avoiding this anti pattern:

```
//BAD
class SomeService {
    public SomeEntity someMethod() {
        try {
            /* stuff... */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //No need to log the exception here
            log.error("An exception happened", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Still, you can have some benefits like wrapping the exceptions and rethrow them:

```
//GOOD
class SomeService {
    public SomeEntity someMethod(String param) {
        try {
            /* stuff... */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //You may use this to perform other logic like setting specific message or wrap your exception
            log.error("Unexpected behaviour with param {}", param);
            throw new MyCustomException("Some message", e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can think of the `@ExceptionHandler` as a giant `catch` block for all your rest endpoints and a specific type of exception.

Besides, your `GlobalExceptionHandler` class becomes the component with logic associated to handle every exception thrown in backend and handles how to report that to client side.

Comment: Good answer! :) One exception (no pun intended) where it is useful to log someting in the method where the exception happends is when you need to log some context you don't have access to in the ```GlobalExceptionHandler```.

Comment: @KajHejer good catch (no pun intended either). Let me rephrase that part, because my intention is to not log the exception stack trace twice.

Comment: I see. So if I need some specific context inside, it would be better to log in the method and if it is generic, it is better to use `@ExceptionHandler`. Good answer. Thanks!